# Workflow REST POST to break inheritance returns Unauthorized

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, rest

I've got a workflow that triggers when a document is updated in a site in SharePoint. The workflow should replace the inherited permissions with custom permissions from the items information.

Workflow, Call HTTP Web Service Info:

- The Call HTTP Web Service Action's response returns: Unauthorized, and the permissions are unchanged.

  - REST Call: `[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]_api/web/lists/getByTitle('[%Workflow Context:List Name%]')/items([%Current Item:ID%])/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false,clearSubscopes=true)`
  - Request Headers are added the the property of the action.

    - Both: Accept and ContentType are included in a Dictionary and have the value of `application/json;odata=verbose`
- The Feature that lets a workflow read and write to items is activated.

So I'm I missing something. Because when I do the same "POST" from JavaScript everything works. The Permissions on the documents are no longer inherited.

```
$.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(\'' + listTitle + '\')/items(\''+ itemId + '\')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false,clearSubscopes=true)',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { 'X-RequestDigest':$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

Comment: Are you using App Step?